# Installing pip to import modules

Tags: python, ubuntu, matplotlib, pip

I am attempting to install matplotlib and scipy to python, and using pip to do so. However when I attempted to install scipy with `pip install scipy --myuser` I received the message:

> invalid requirement '--myuser'

Previously I had installed numpy using pip with

```
python get-pip.py —myuser
```

and

```
pip install numpy —myuser
```

This worked fine, so I am unsure what the problem is here.

This is frustrating as I would like to use python from the terminal rather than from my Windows desktop.

Comment: have you tried `sudo python3 -m pip install scipy`?

Comment: I think when I shut down the terminal earlier on I may have uninstalled pip, as on using sudo I am recieving the message "no module named pip". Have tried using wget https... which works fine but on calling python get-pip.py -user I am recieving the same 'invalid requirement -user' message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to install it without the use of the --myuser argument.

```
sudo python3 -m pip install scipy
sudo python3 -m pip install matplotlib
```

or all in one

```
sudo python3 -m pip install scipy matplotlib
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to install to user try the below mentioned command:

```
pip install --user scipy
```

Here is the help from pip command:

```
pip install --help

  --user                      Install to the Python user install directory for
                              your platform. Typically ~/.local/, or
                              %APPDATA%\Python on Windows. (See the Python
                              documentation for site.USER_BASE for full
                              details.)
```

Comment: I'm getting an error "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-uh5QQI/matplotlib/". I have installed setuptools and dev but to no avail

Comment: My guess is you have multiple version of pip installed. Could you try with pip3? eg. `pip3 install --user scipy`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`sudo python3 -m pip install scipy matplotlib`

Comment: inline multiple modules install

Comment: It is telling me 'no module named pip' when I try this method. Pip is definitely installed and updated however.

Comment: have u tried just `sudo python -m pip install scipy metaplotlib` ?